# AnimationController methods should not be used after calling dispose

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm using an animation library by the name animate_do https://pub.dev/packages/animate_do to animate a widget inside PageView. The problem is when I try to swipe to the next page but halfway between I decide to return to the page, I get this error

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 772 pos 7: '_ticker != null': AnimationController.stop() called after AnimationController.dispose()
E/flutter (15395): AnimationController methods should not be used after calling dispose.
```

What I think is that the animationController is being `disposed` whenever `onPageChanged` of the Pageview is called, and since I'm still on the same page, the animationController is not initialized again. Can anyone help me with how to solve this?

This is the code of the widget to animate:

```
FadeOutUp(
                        animate: false,
                        controller: (controller) =>
                            animateController = controller,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 36,
                          width: 36,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '-',
                                style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    letterSpacing: .5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '1',
                                style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    letterSpacing: .5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

This is the code for triggering animation:

```
InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            animateController.reset();
                            animateController.forward();
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
```

Edit to include the complete code:

```
late AnimationController animateController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

....
return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 1,
                  title: Row(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          ///open bottom sheet
                       
                        },
                        child: Image(
                          height: 40,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: AssetImage(
                            'assets/images/512_transparent_bg.png',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 8.0,
                          right: 10.0,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 20,
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        //height: 26,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.teal.withOpacity(.1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(4.0),
                          ),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.teal,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 10.0,
                            vertical: 4.0,
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                CupertinoIcons.star,
                                color: Colors.black87,
                                size: 11,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 4.0,
                              ),
                              AnimatedFlipCounter(
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds:500),
                                value: _value,
                                textStyle: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    letterSpacing: .5,
                                    color:Colors.green,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    filter(),
                    _notificationMessage(0),
                    _notificationBell(0),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('Accounts')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Container(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.cloud_download,
                            size: 56,
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.5),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      if (snapshot.data!.docs.length == 0) {
                        return Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.cloud_download,
                              size: 56,
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.5),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return PageView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          allowImplicitScrolling: false,
                          onPageChanged: (val) {
                            print(val);
                          },
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot singlePerson =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index];

                            return personItem(
                              index,
                              singlePerson,
                              snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              );

....
Widget personItem(int index, DocumentSnapshot singlePerson, int count) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        PageView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          pageSnapping: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(singlePerson['user_slide_images'][0]),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '1',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/3',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(singlePerson['user_slide_images'][1]),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '2',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/3',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(singlePerson['user_slide_images'][2]),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '3',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '/3',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

        ///Info layer
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      stops: [
                        0.3,
                        0.9,
                      ],
                      colors: [
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(.9),
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(.5),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 24,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  singlePerson['user_name'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      letterSpacing: .5,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 4.0,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 20,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 16,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.5),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble_text_fill,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    size: 16,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.star,
                              color: Colors.white54,
                              size: 14,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                ///open counter info
                                showDialog(
                                  barrierDismissible: true,
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return Dialog(
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                      ), //this right here
                                      child: quickInfo(
                                        'Title text',
                                        'Lorem ipsum...',
                                        context,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                '${singlePerson['total_balance'].toString()} Coins',
                                style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12.0,
                                    color: Colors.white54,
                                    letterSpacing: .5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 28,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.map_pin_ellipse,
                              color: Colors.white54,
                              size: 14,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '${singlePerson['location']',
                              style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  color: Colors.white54,
                                  letterSpacing: .5,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 6.0,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50),
                          child: Text(
                            singlePerson['about_user'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.7),
                                height: 1.2,
                                fontSize: 14),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              ///Button layer
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 10,
                child: Container(
                  //color: Colors.grey,
                  //width: 200,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      FadeOutUp(
                        animate: false,
                        controller: (controller) =>
                            animateController = controller,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 36,
                          width: 36,
                          // color: Colors.red,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '-',
                                style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    letterSpacing: .5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '1',
                                style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    letterSpacing: .5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      LikeButton(
                        isLiked: null,
                        onTap: (isLiked) async {
                          ///Do center animation
                          setState(() {
                            animateController.reset();
                            animateController.forward();
                          });

                          ///Do center animation
                          DocumentReference ds = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('Accounts')
                              .doc(singlePerson['user_id']);
                          Map<String, dynamic> tasks = {
                           
                            'user_total_balance': FieldValue.increment(1),
                          };
                          ds.update(tasks);
                          DocumentReference myRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('Accounts')
                              .doc(userId);
                          Map<String, dynamic> myRefTask = {
                           
                            'user_total_balance': FieldValue.increment(-1),
                          };
                          myRef.update(myRefTask);
                          return !isLiked;
                        },
                        size: 36,
                        circleColor: CircleColor(
                            start: Color(0xff00ddff), end: Color(0xff225675)),
                        bubblesColor: BubblesColor(
                          dotPrimaryColor: Color(0xff33b5e5),
                          dotSecondaryColor: Color(0xff225675),
                        ),
                        likeBuilder: (bool isLiked) {
                          return Container(
                            height: 36,
                            width: 36,
                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xff225675),
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(18.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.star,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        likeCount: null,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the full widget?

Comment: Can you try with overriding dispose and  `animateController.dispose()`

Comment: Where did you initialize your `animationController`?

Comment: @quoci I believe it's initialized upon building the widget, by the library itself. In the controller parameter.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you please show me in code how I can do that?

Comment: `late AnimationController animateController;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    animateController.dispose();`

Comment: But dispose is called when I leave the screen by pressing the back button, but the problem here is animateController is disposed while still on the same screen.